# Return to current state of file after issuing :earlier command?

Tags: undo-redo

Sometimes I want to get back and copy some old code that I deleted and use it. For example, I'll do:

`:earlier 12h`

and then yank the deleted code.

To get back to where I was, I'll issue a command like:

`:later 13h`

with the time argument for the `:later` command being longer than the time argument I supplied for the `:earlier` command.

This works, but it seems like there should be a cleaner way to jump back to the latest version of the code. I can't seem to find a command to do that, though.

Comment: Change your workflow with git and fugitive?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble that's a good point. You can always use `:Glog` in fugitive to load older revisions of the file, or `:Gdiff <revision>` to view the differences in vimdiff mode. I would consider that a better practice than `:earlier`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't write the current buffer, and you probably don't need to if you are just looking back to yank some stuff, you can use `:edit!` (or simply `:e!`) to reload the file from disk, thus undoing all those changes.

Answer (score 2):

How about, in Normal mode, <kbd>9</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> ?

From `:h CTRL-R`:

```
CTRL-R      Redo [count] changes which were undone.
```

If you overshoot it's okay. You can't go past the most recent change. (To the future?)

Of course, you can use any sufficiently high number. 999 is just a quick way to a number likely to do the job. If not add another <kbd>9</kbd> or two. Just hammer on it until you feel good about it. ;)

Comment: If my boss finds out I only make 99 edits in *12 hours* of work I am going to be in *trouble*.

Comment: @Rich Heh. Do you spend a lot of time 100+ entries back looking for stuff? Boss might wonder why you are making slow progress...stuck in the past. ;) Seriously, though, how many is it? Would 999 do it? (My max is 3000 but I've never looked that far back.)

Comment: I actually have no idea. I’d imagine 999 would cover it, but to be on the safe side I’d probably go with 9999. Like you said, you can’t overshoot!

Comment: Either way...you convinced me. I'm going with 999..9999. Fortunately it's about 100ms difference. :)